# variable of a base class that uses generics

Tags: swift, generics

I have a abstract base class (DataSource, in my simplified scenario below) and a handful of subclasses (IntSource and StringSource). The base class is using generics.

I want to have a variable (say, currentDataSource) typed as the base class so it can refer to an instance of any of the subclasses. I can't figure out how to declare it, though. The declaration requires a concrete type which immediately breaks the abstraction.

```
class DataSource<Element> where Element:Equatable {
    var elements = [Element]()
    func description() {
        print("must override")
    }
}

class IntSource: DataSource<Int> {
    override func description() {
        print("Ints!")
    }
}

class StringSource: DataSource<String> {
    override func description() {
        print("Strings!")
    }
}

let a = IntSource()
let b = StringSource()
var current: DataSource<???> // this is where I'm stuck

current = a
print(current.description())
current = b
print(current.description())
```

Comment: `DataSource` makes more sense as a Protocol with an associated type. From there you could make a type eraser, `AnyDataSource`, that does what you're looking for

Comment: I spent a day digging into that direction and ended up with the same problem. Using the playgrounds here: https://github.com/bignerdranch/type-erasure-playgrounds, I tried `var pokemon: AnyPokemon = AnyPokemon(Pikachu())` followed by `pokemon = AnyPokemon(Charmander())` which fails.

Comment: Well you have to one make one modification: `AnyPokemon` can't be generic, it would just store the variables as `Any` rather than a generic type `T`